# Hidden gems of Metafont that are still worth it?

Tags: fonts, conversion, metafont

I've read up on the conversion from METAFONT to OTF via `mf2pt1` and FontForge.

Are there some "forgotten" fonts where such a conversion would make sense?

I'd rather use Latin Modern than try to do all the conversion work from CM myself. (And I seriously doubt my artfulness to do it better.) But are there some fonts that were *not* converted to modern formats, where a conversion would make sense?

Comment: `cmsy` is not available in OpenType format.

Comment: I just found it in BaKoMa collection on CTAN, also as OTF.

Comment: Would this be of interest? Not exactly what you asked. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403401/do-the-latex-2-09-hebrew-fonts-have-truetype-opentype-versions

Comment: That's roughly the procedure, I'd apply, if I'd find something interesting to apply it to. The latter is what I am asking for here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there still exist worthwhile fonts that exist in METAFONT format and are not already available in OTF.

A couple of examples are the Devanagari (Sanskrit) fonts by Velthuis and Wikner: see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/358887/old-sanskrit-fonts-and-unicode-input) for details on what these fonts are, and what has been done already. The interesting addition here would be to remap the glyphs from the font to their Unicode points, and to set up GSUB rules, etc. This would be worthwhile to do, as there is still some interest in using those fonts. I think there exist other similar examples of Non-Latin fonts (for example the fonts inside `bangtex` and `bengali`, in the directory mentioned below).

More generally, you can look inside the `/texmf-dist/fonts/source/public` directory in a TeX Live distribution. (One from many years ago is [here](https://github.com/jpallen/latex-chroot/tree/master/usr/share/texmf-texlive/fonts/source/public).) Or even go one level higher…

One interesting font that is of historical interest would have been the Punk METAFONT, which [Knuth wrote about in TUGboat](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb09-2/tb21knut.pdf), after creating it in a single afternoon:

> At 1 p.m. I went to the computer and began to compose a simple base file. […] by 4 p.m. I was ready to make the first trial setting of text

But it looks like this has already been converted to OTF by Khaled Hosny; see the [`punknova` package on CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/punknova) or [his `punk-otf` GitHub repo](https://github.com/khaledhosny/punk-otf).